# How to make JQuery work after reload content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a  block(div) where i  use to put information. I have a hidden form there? and it shows on click. But If I reload data in block(div) it works like link .

This is my script:

```
var comment_block ;
var show_comment_block;
var show;
$(function(){
    $('A.reply').on('click',ShowCommentBlock);
});

function ShowCommentBlock(){
    $(this).parent().next('.answer-form').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
}
```

And it is the code on my button:

```
<a class="reply" href="#comment<?php echo $comment['comment_id']?>">Ответить</a>
```

As i understand after content reload in block(div) i have to put this actions on new forms?
I dont understand how to do that? or maybe there is some other kind of solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: post a fiddle to help ur cause...I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: You have to use delegation, e.g: `$(document.body).on('click','A.reply', ShowCommentBlock);`

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', 'A.reply', ShowCommentBlock);` Damn it @A.Wolff :P

Comment: i have a block. there is a hidden form. i have a button that shows this form after click. This block i use to reload by ajax. After reload, my link that should show me my form sends me by adress www.example.com/#comment but should just show me block.

Comment: I'd suggest to put the delegate on the div and not on entire $(document). You don't want to wait for the click event to bubble up to the document root, you want to catch it on the div which gets its contents reloaded. Also, I highly suggest you to read some articles about DOM event bubbling - it is crucial to understand how to use them effectively and do many useful things. Otherwise it would take much trials and errors if you don't know anything about event bubbling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use delegation, e.g:

```
$(document.body).on('click','A.reply', ShowCommentBlock);
```

A. Wolff

Thank U!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe change it to:

```
 $('A.reply').live("click", ShowCommentBlock);
```

Comment: The live is deprecated.

Comment: live is deleted from latest jquery library and .on suggested for it to delegate the event.

Comment: I guess, we could say that "live" must die :D Yes, a delegate is the way to go, and it would be better to set it not on entire body or document but on the parent of the a.reply element.